# Webpack with mocha-loader nextTick is not a function

Tags: webpack, mocha.js, webpack-dev-server

I use webpack with mocha-loader plugin. And I have an console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).nextTick is not a function(…)
```

webpack.config.js:

```
...
target: 'web',
entry: {
    app: [path.resolve(applicationConfig.source.path, 'app.js')],
    vendors: [path.resolve(applicationConfig.source.path, 'vendors.js')],
    testing: 'mocha!' + path.resolve(applicationConfig.source.path, 'testing.js')
},
...
```

I run tests from /testing.html file
testing.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mocha</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="./testing.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Mocha-loader have start.js file:

```
process.nextTick(function() {
    delete require.cache[module.id];
    if(typeof window !== "undefined" && window.mochaPhantomJS)
        mochaPhantomJS.run();
    else
        mocha.run();
});
```

After webpack work it looks like this:

```
({"env":{"NODE_ENV":"development"}}).nextTick(function() {
    delete __webpack_require__.c[module.id];
    if(typeof window !== "undefined" && window.mochaPhantomJS)
        mochaPhantomJS.run();
    else
        mocha.run();
});
```

I'l can be use polyfill with process.nextTick (https://gist.github.com/WebReflection/2953527) but I can't after replacing of process variable.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    process: {
        env: {
            NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development')
        }
    },
    __DEV__: true
}),
```

to

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development')
    },
    __DEV__: true
}),
```

And code works